# How to join in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, join

Consider the following list of tables:

```
listtemp[n_] := Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}], n];
```

How to join its elements at the level 2 in a compact way for arbitrary n?

Say, for

```
list5=listtemp[5];
```

the desired result obtained in the tedious way is

```
Join[list5[[1]],list5[[2]],list5[[3]],list5[[4]],list5[[5]],2];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
Join[##, 2] & @@ list5
```

or

```
 Join[Sequence @@ list5, 2]
```